# ImportDocumentationPartsCommandInput - Missing 'body' param?

Tags: javascript, aws-api-gateway, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I'm getting this error when sending the **ImportDocumentationPartsCommand** command "errorMessage": "1 validation error detected: Value null at 'body' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null"

The **ImportDocumentationPartsCommandInput** interface doesn't have a body param so I opted to using 'any' to test it but I still get the validation error.

```
const input: any = {
    body: JSON.stringify(swaggerSpec),
    restApiId: "jisaf123",
    mode: "merge",
  };
```

**Edit 1 - Added request**

```
{ body:
   '{"openapi":"3.0.0","info":{"title":"Frisk API","version":"0.0.1","description":"Documentation for Frisk API"},"paths":{"/":{"get":{"description":"Welcome to swagger-jsdoc!","responses":{"200":{"description":"Returns a mysterious string."}}}}},"components":{},"tags":[]}',
  restApiId: 'jisaf123',
  mode: 'merge' }
```

Comment: `swaggerSpec` is probably `null`

Comment: Just checked it again and it exists!